# Sort array of NSManagedObjects based on second array

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to sort an array of `NSManagedObject` based on values associated to each of them. These values are expensive to compute so I want to compute them at most once. Most solutions for similar questions involve constructing a `NSDictionary` but my object does not (necessarily) conform to `NSCopying` protocol. I have thought about using the object id but is there maybe a cleaner/simpler solution ? Is there any catch with this method ?

Comment: You can use NSMapTable or CFDictionary in cases where your keys do not conform to NSCopying. Or perhaps you could add conformance to NSCopying to your key classes via a category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an embarrassingly simple solution to my problem. I can just create a dictionary whose keys are the indices of my objects in their array, and whose associated value are those that are associated with the objects. I sort the dictionary by value and then retrieve the objects in the order given by the keys.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a convenience method in the `NSManagedObject` subclass that calculates the value you need to sort by and will return it.  Code it so that it only calculates the value once.
2. Sort by the convenience method.

### Update to OP

> Can you elaborate on how you do 1. ? Should I use NSCache ? Thanks

You subclass `NSManagedObject`:

```
@interface MySubclass: NSManagedObject
@property NSString *myCalculatedSortValue;

- (NSString*)calculatedSortValue;

@end
```

Then you implement it in a lazy fashion:

```
@implementation MySubclass

- (NSString*)calculatedSortValue
{
  if (myCalculatedSortValue) return myCalculatedSortValue;
  //calculate value
  return myCalculatedSortValue;
}
```

Then you can sort by `calculatedSortValue` and it will only get calculated once per lifecycle.

**NOTE:** This will only work *after* the `NSManagedObject` instances have been fetched from the store.  This will not work directly against the store because all of the calculations are occurring in object-space.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you do 1. ? Should I use NSCache ? The associated values may change over time, do I need to manually invalidate the cache when needed ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this forces me (unless I am mistaken) to 1. save one more property in my persistent store  2. handle when to re-compute this property manually (e.g if something my computation depend upon has changed)

Comment: No, the value does **NOT** get stored.  It is computed once per lifecycle of the object; exactly what you requested.  If the underlying values changes you will of course need to recalculate it.  There is no way to avoid that in any design.

Comment: why not use a category instead of a subclass?

Comment: Ok for your answer to 1, but I don't agree with 2. If I could put my objects in a dictionary (when I want to sort them) then I would avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: You look for an answer and then argue?  Good luck!

Comment: @nielsbot a category does not allow you to implement the method, just declare it.  Also, in my implementations I would be adding more functions to the subclasses anyway.

Comment: @Marcus that's not correct. you can add implementation (using `@implementation MyClass (CategoryName)`) and I use this a lot. in fact the @interface portion is unnecessary. (this is not the case for protocols however)

Comment: @nielsbot That is implementing a category and isn't any better than doing a subclass.  I prefer to subclass `NSManagedObject`; in fact I generally use mogenerator and have two levels of subclasses.

Comment: I disagree. You can add capabilities to all instances of a class without changing your code to use a specific subclass everywhere. Perhaps that doesn't matter for _NSManagedObject_, but in general I think composition (has-a relationships) are more flexible than subclassing (is-a relationships)